# Failed to notify project evaluation listener: ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native

I'm getting error when i try to run android code in reactnative using

```
react-native run-android
```

- Where:
  Script '/Users/mini2018/Projects/ReactNative/Name_Project/ProjectTest/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' line: 35
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  >   react_5683z1abwb63lrwfba0beuw5p$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3

Project dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
```

Comment: Once delete node_module folder and reInstall it after that open android folder in android studio and  try to clean and rebuild it , then run through command from Vs